# MVVM Pattern in Swift Example

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, mvvm

I try to create MVVM Pattern with Swift for Ios Project. I Researched various resources from Internet. Finally I created following for MVVM. It's Working fine. But I don't know it is MVVM Code or Not. Please Explain Any One.

This is the Example Parsing The Data from API to Label. https://the-flash@bitbucket.org/the-flash/samplemvvm.git

**View**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SampleMVVM
//
//  Created by ADMIN on 20/02/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ADMIN. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ClassLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        service().forStudentName { cName, cClass in
            let custViewModel = ViewModel(data: Model(myName: cName[0], myClass: cClass[0]))

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.NameLabel.text = custViewModel.CustName
                self.ClassLabel.text = custViewModel.CustClass
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View Model**

APICall.swift

```
//
//  APICall.swift
//  SampleMVVM
//
//  Created by ADMIN on 20/02/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ADMIN. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

struct service{

    func forStudentName(completionBlock: @escaping (Array<String>, Array<String>) -> Void) {
        var CstmrName = Array<String>()
        var CstmrClass = Array<String>()

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: DefaultData.Base().Url)!){ data, response, error in

            guard let jsonData = data else { return }

            do {
                let studentData = try JSONDecoder().decode(StudentData.self, from: jsonData)
                for index in studentData.studentdetails{
                    CstmrName.append(index.studentname)
                    CstmrClass.append(index.studentdetailClass)
                }
                completionBlock(CstmrName, CstmrClass)

            }catch let error  {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

ViewModel.swift

```
//
//  ViewModel.swift
//  SampleMVVM
//
//  Created by ADMIN on 20/02/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ADMIN. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewModel: NSObject {
    var CustName: String?
    var CustClass: String?

    init(data: Model) {
        self.CustName = data.CustomerName
        self.CustClass = data.CustomerClass
    }
}
```

**Model**

Model.swift

```
//
//  Model.swift
//  SampleMVVM
//
//  Created by ADMIN on 20/02/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ADMIN. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

//https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4kobjnVE8

/****************************** Student Name Model *********************************/
class Model: NSObject {

    var CustomerName: String?
    var CustomerClass: String?

    init(myName: String, myClass: String) {
        CustomerName = myName
        CustomerClass = myClass
    }
}

/****************************** JSON Parsing Model *********************************/

struct StudentData: Codable {
    let studentdetails: [Studentdetail]
}
struct Studentdetail: Codable {
    let school, studentname, studentdetailClass, board: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case school, studentname
        case studentdetailClass = "class"
        case board
    }
}
```

DefaultData.swift

```
//
//  DefaultData.swift
//  SampleMVVM
//
//  Created by ADMIN on 20/02/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 ADMIN. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

class DefaultData: NSObject {

    struct Base {
        let Url: String = "https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4kobjnVE8"
    }
}
```

***Advanced Thanks for Your Valuable Answers!!!***

Comment: You should first adopt the Swift naming convention and name all your variables (instance properties of your class or struct) starting with a lowercase lt

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Swift.